# After upgrade to Angular 1.2 problems linking to an anchor tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I recently upgraded to angular 1.2 and any links to anchor tags are now being converted from:

```
http://homepath.com#my_anchor
```

to

```
http://homepath.com/my_anchor
```

Any suggestions on preventing that?

For instance, in my nav bar, I have the following:

```
link_to('my anchor', root_path(:anchor => 'my_anchor'))
```

When clicked it consistently reroutes to `http://homepath.com/my_anchor`, but this was working fine before the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this has anything to do with html5 mode. You could try adding `$locationProvider` to your apps config function and enforcing no html5 mode. For example:

```
myapp.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {

    // turn html5 mode off
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
}]);
```

Comment: this might work, but i really doubt there is was change in default value of html5Mode. also on all the anchors you have to write the link with #, it wont work otherwise. i am doing it since i started working using angularjs - v1.0.8